# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to connect to the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I am very new to Ubuntu and I have encountered a problem where I cannot connect to the internet through both wifi and ethernet.

I am using a B550m-plus gaming wifi motherboard and I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed onto my E drive. I wanted Ubuntu to be a stand-alone drive instead of mixing it with Windows on my other drives. Upon log-in, the only thing I see in networks settings are options to connect to a VPN. I have no option to connect to either ethernet or wifi, which are available since I can connect to both when I am on Windows. The network icon that is supposed to be available at the top right corner is missing too.

I've looked through various sources and they pointed me towards having missing chipset drivers. So I followed the instructions to Realtek and downloaded the "2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125" driver. Unfortunately, what followed was a flurry of missing drivers that I could not install because I have no internet connection. Any tips on how to solve this?

Edit: here are some pictures which show what I am seeing.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bi7u4mwlcxq2fio/AADhAZz-w1jLK4t1u1yRP3Q_a?dl=0

Comment: Is there a way to connect the computer via wired internet (ethernet)?

Comment: Unable to do so. I am using a homeplug connected to my modem from my another room, if that helps.

Comment: You can use a phone to connect and install the driver for Ethernet.

Comment: Yes, two homeplug units (one at the router and one at the computer) plus ethernet cables should work well, if an ethernet cable can be plugged into your computer. It should also work to connect via a mobile phone as suggested by Pilot6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 to my hard drive without checking the "install 3rd party drivers" at the boot menu. This installs a driver for my Wifi module which I then use to install the other modules needed (such as gcc and make) before installing r8125.

I can now use both Wifi and Ethernet connections.

Comment: That's great work appreciate coming back and posting what you've found yourself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your assistance on this question. I appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking r8125 from your question and considering that's your device's model number.

Find the file [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/directly-download?downloadid=54c0e3e95c579555ee0cd61b8eaca701). Give your email address and follow captcha verfication, download and extract the archive. You might need another medium to copy the archive to the target machine and I'm assuming you have tried something and I leave it up to you. In the extracted folder you'll see autorun.sh file. Open terminal there and execute

```
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

You might need to give execution permission to the file but you'll figure that out. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried that before and here are the results, which is where I am stuck. When I execute that command now, it tells me that configx86x32 enabled but with no binutils support and GCC command not found. I tried manually installing GCC but it leads to more and more package dependencies. I have a link to show what I've experienced. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bi7u4mwlcxq2fio/AADhAZz-w1jLK4t1u1yRP3Q_a?dl=0