# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't connect to the internet... Sometimes

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu for the first time and split my drive (now a part of it is Windows and a part is Ubuntu). Normally everything is fine (Ubuntu connects to the internet regularly), but every week or so the Ubuntu split doesn't connect to the internet. When I restart the computer and switch to Windows it can connect to the WiFi just fine. In fact, it's quite random, but after one or several restarts Ubuntu is finally connecting the the WiFi.

I found several SO questions ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301377/ubuntu-20-04-unable-to-connect-to-the-internet), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312023/ubuntu-20-04-cant-connect-to-the-internet-anymore)) about Ubuntu not connecting to the internet, but they seem to be related to Ubuntu not connecting to the internet at all (and not like mine which is sporadically).

I believe my make/model of the wifi is `Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200`

Comment: Wifi issues are generally hardware specific. What is the make/model of the wifi adapter that you use?

Comment: Not sure if it's this so let me know. `Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200`

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.  Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: whose wifi router is it? can you access it?

Comment: @Andra My router

Comment: when this situation occurs (Ubuntu cannot internet), first, I would try to open the router management page - it would be also over wifi? If the page opens, see if there is an old lease (delete it), maybe some other parameters. And from Ubuntu side I would use Wireshark to see that the request is issued and what replies received.